# Thevenin seems unclear

Tags: thevenin

How do I find these answers? For the first example, `R` = 3/22, on the second it equals 18/17.

I don't see how these will help me find `i` and `Vth`.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already solved for you by Sunnyskygut EE75, the following logic applies.

1. \$V_1=3\:\text{V}\$ and \$I_1=22\:\text{A}\$, \$\therefore R_1=\frac{V_1}{I_1}\$.
2. \$V_2=18\:\text{V}\$ and \$I_1=17\:\text{A}\$, \$\therefore R_2=\frac{V_2}{I_2}\$.
3. \$V_\text{TH}\$ and \$R_\text{TH}\$ are both unknown.

Given that \$V_n=V_\text{TH}\cdot\frac{R_n}{R_n+R_\text{TH}}\$ you can find there are two equations and two unknowns:

$$\begin{align*}V_1&=V_\text{TH}\cdot\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_\text{TH}}=V_\text{TH}\cdot\frac{\frac{V_1}{I_1}}{\frac{V_1}{I_1}+R_\text{TH}}\\\\V_2&=V_\text{TH}\cdot\frac{R_2}{R_2+R_\text{TH}}=V_\text{TH}\cdot\frac{\frac{V_2}{I_2}}{\frac{V_2}{I_2}+R_\text{TH}}\end{align*}$$

The simultaneous solution is:

$$\begin{align*}V_\text{TH}&=\frac{V_2\cdot I_1-V_1\cdot I_2}{I_1-I_2}\\\\R_\text{TH}&=\frac{V_2-V_1}{I_1-I_2}\end{align*}$$

Not overly complex. But you need to keep track of the details.